# Filter rows in dataframe by number of rows per level of a factor

Tags: r, filter, dataframe

I have a data frame set up with one column as a factor with several levels. I'd like to extract rows that do not have a unique value for that column (i.e. the level is present in multiple rows).

So for some simple test data:

```
factor dat1 dat2 dat3
     a  1.0  1.0  1.0
     a  1.0  0.9  1.0
     b  0.9  0.8  0.6
     c  0.9  1.0  0.0
```

I'd like to retain only the first two rows. What is the best way to do this? Preferrably I'd like to make more general queries, i.e. extract rows for levels of the factor present in at least 3 rows, exactly 2 rows, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with `table` (assuming the data frame's name is `df`):

```
nRows <- 2 # minimum number of occurrences

tab <- table(df$factor) # count

df[df$factor %in% names(tab)[tab >= nRows], ] # extract rows
```

If you want to use an exact criterion instead, change `>=` to `==`.

The result:

```
  factor dat1 dat2 dat3
1      a    1  1.0    1
2      a    1  0.9    1
```

Comment: Thanks! I'd only gotten as far as `table()`

Answer (score 1):

For these types of problems, I like to use `ave()` to generate a vector of the same length as the number of rows in my dataset to match against. I find it a little bit more direct than having to refer to `names()` as is required with the `table()` approach:

```
## Your data
mydf <- read.table(header = TRUE, 
          stringsAsFactors = FALSE, 
          text = "factor dat1 dat2 dat3
                  a  1.0  1.0  1.0
                  a  1.0  0.9  1.0
                  b  0.9  0.8  0.6
                  c  0.9  1.0  0.0")

## Your vector to match against
factorlengths <- ave(as.numeric(mydf$factor), 
                     mydf$factor, FUN = length)
factorlengths
# [1] 2 2 1 1

## The subsetting
mydf[factorlengths > 1, ]
#   factor dat1 dat2 dat3
# 1      a    1  1.0    1
# 2      a    1  0.9    1
mydf[factorlengths == 1, ]
#   factor dat1 dat2 dat3
# 3      b  0.9  0.8  0.6
# 4      c  0.9  1.0  0.0
```

If the values of `mydf$factor` are actually factors, you'll have to use `ave(as.numeric(as.character(mydf$factor...` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a different approach for your consideration:

```
mydf <- data.frame(fac = c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "e"),
dat1 = rnorm(7), dat2 = rnorm(7), dat3 = rnorm(7))

library("plyr")

cts <- count(mydf, vars = "fac")
keep <- as.character(subset(cts, freq > 1)$fac)
keep2 <- mydf$fac %in% keep
mydf2 <- mydf[keep2,]
```

Which converts:

```
  fac        dat1       dat2       dat3
1   a  0.83565861  0.2293744 -1.2932864
2   a -0.05509087  0.1995655 -1.7961443
3   b -0.82794260  1.6314641 -0.3622872
4   c  0.13907037 -0.4560306 -0.3751849
5   d -0.30057042  0.8347340  0.4798789
6   d -1.15576099 -0.5945094 -0.3124572
7   e  1.17671034  0.1453544 -2.6906382
```

to:

```
  fac        dat1       dat2       dat3
1   a  0.83565861  0.2293744 -1.2932864
2   a -0.05509087  0.1995655 -1.7961443
5   d -0.30057042  0.8347340  0.4798789
6   d -1.15576099 -0.5945094 -0.3124572
```

I thought there might be a one-liner using `duplicated` but that doesn't quite return what is needed in this case.